# Detect a Parallelogram from an Image using opencv and Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

[Parallelogram in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnkXw.png)

I want to Detect Parallelogram in an Image using Opencv and numpy in python Language.I have tried it from contour detection and successfully detected Rectangle and Square but unable to detect shapes like parallelogram and rhombus,can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Find all 4 sided objects. Then look at the angle of the edges. If opposite sides are parallel but the angle of two opposite edges are not a multiple of 90, then you have a parallelogram (provided the parallelograms are not rotated from what you showed). The definition is : "A parallelogram is a shape with four sides, and the sides opposite each other are parallel and equal length, meaning they don't intersect. Examples of parallelograms include squares, rhombuses, and rectangles. Circles, triangles, and trapezoids are not parallelograms."

Comment: There are three special types of a parallelogram.
Rhombus: A parallelogram in which all sides are equal.
Rectangle: A parallelogram in which all angles are right angles and the diagonals are equal.
Square: A parallelogram with all equal sides and all angles equal to 90 degrees. The diagonals of a square are also equal.

Comment: Parallelograms are quadrilaterals that have two sets of parallel sides and two sets of congruent sides. A parallelogram's opposite angles are congruent; its consecutive angles are supplementary; its diagonals bisect each other and its diagonals form two congruent triangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. detect contours
2. draw straight lines on the contours (maybe with approxyPolyDP)
3. calculate the angle of every corner
4. make sure opposite corners are congruent (within a margin) and corners next to eachother add up to 180.

I have previously written a some code to calculate the angle between 3 point of a vector. which could help.

```
def angle(pt1, pt2, pt0):
# For A(x,y), B(x,y), C(x,y)
#  vectorAB = B-A = ((Bx-Ax)-(By-Ay))
#  vectorBC = C-B = ((Cx-Bx)-(Cy-By))
# dx1 = pt1x-coordinate - pt0x-coordinate
dx1 = pt1[0][0] - pt0[0][0]
dy1 = pt1[0][1] - pt0[0][1]
# vectorAB
d1 = np.array([dx1, dy1])

# vectorBC
dx2 = pt2[0][0] - pt0[0][0]
dy2 = pt2[0][1]  - pt0[0][1]
d2 = np.array([dx2, dy2])

# dot product of d1 en d2
# dotPrd1d2= d2(x)*d1(x)+d2(y)*d1(y)
dotPr = np.dot(d1, d2)
# ||AB|| = sqrt(math.pow(vectorABx, 2) + math.pow(VectorABy,2))
# ||BC|| = sqrt(math.pow(vectorBCx, 2) + math.pow(vectorBCy,2))
lengthOfd1 = math.sqrt(math.pow(dx1,2) + math.pow(dy1, 2))
lengthOfd2 = math.sqrt(math.pow(dx2, 2) + math.pow(dy2, 2))
# returns the angle of the vector by arc cos alpha
return np.arccos(dotPr/(lengthOfd1*lengthOfd2))
```

I have written some comments to help. I haven't extensively tested it, so be careful.